# How to convert a Percentage data type to an Int

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to convert a `percentage` column into a `int` column to its right. I'll include my code and what I'm currently getting.

```
Sub percentToInt()
    'setting workbooks
    Set wsSheetTo = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Scratch Pad")
    Set wsSheetFrom = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Scratch Pad")
    
    'changing lesson prgoress to an int and putting in column e
    'declaring loop variables
    Dim FromRow As Long
    Dim ToRow As Long
    Dim FromTotalRows As Long
    Dim LCounter As Long
    
    FromTotalRows = lMaxNumStudents  'Max number of students
    For LCounter = 1 To FromTotalRows
        ToRow = LCounter + 1 ' We need to start at 2
        FromRow = LCounter + 1 'start from row 2
        If wsSheetFrom.Cells(FromRow, 4) = "" Then
            Exit For
        End If
        wsSheetTo.Cells(FromRow, 5).Value = Format(wsSheetFrom.Cells(FromRow, 4), "Standard")
    Next
End Sub
```

I've included a photo of what I'm getting right now.

[image]

Also I don't want any values chopped off, It's going into a gradebook so the decimals matter.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You don't show your expected results. And if you convert a percentage to an Integer, by definition there are no decimals.   Perhaps all you need to do is multiply by 100?

Comment: Sorry its unclear, I'm literally looking for 99.58% > 99.58 .

Comment: `99.58` is not an integer.  In any event, as I wrote, merely multiply your result by 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
wsSheetTo.Cells(FromRow, 5).Value = Format(wsSheetFrom.Cells(FromRow, 4), "Standard")
```

with:

```
wsSheetTo.Cells(FromRow, 5).Value = wsSheetFrom.Cells(FromRow, 4) * 100
```

and format the column to display as many decimal places as you need:

[image]